# Does PCA transform preserve the sorting of the data?

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, pca

I am working with a huge number of n-dimensional arrays in python. All the arrays are stored in a dictionary, so each array is uniquely identified by a key.
I would like to visualize all the arrays in 2D, so I have performed a PCA:

```
# standardize data before applying PCA
dict_data_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(dict_data.values()) 

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
data_post_pca = pca.fit_transform(dict_data_std.values())
```

My problem is: does PCA transform preserve the order of the data? So, does the first array of `dict_data` get mapped to the first (2D) array of `data_post_pca`?

I need a 100% certain answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. You can think of PCA with one eigenvector as a weighted linear combination of input. Depending on the decomposition it could do anything from reordering to reversing the weights. However, if your intuition holds true it should produce a weighting similar to what you think it should.

Now once you take more eigenvectors it becomes a set of linear combinations instead of a single one. - https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/24ywyc/does_pca_preserve_the_order_in_data/